# После установки composer open server не может запуститься

Tags: php

Красный флажек есть,желтый есть, а зеленого нет.

Comment: посмотрите логи

Comment: Нашел решение.У меня компосер не работает с версией php 5.4 поэтому я поставил php 7 и для нее нужно выбрать apache 7

Comment: @user262300 добавьте ответ

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 0):

@user262300 **Ответ**:

> Нашел решение.У меня компосер не работает с версией php 5.4 поэтому я
>   поставил php 7 и для нее нужно выбрать apache 7